# Which language is the Nitrotasks application for Ubuntu developed in?

Tags: javascript

I need to know in which language nitrotasks is developed. I just downloaded their source from https://github.com/stayradiated/Nitro/. it is just html, css, and js. How did they create Ubuntu apps using that?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Is Javascript not good enough?

Comment: I did not mean that. He build an application with just java script. Its an standalone version in ubuntu.I just need to know how the javascript,html,css are built into an application.

Comment: No it also have an standalone version in ubuntu i am asking about that.http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/task-app-nitro-adds-theme-support/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably asking how they made a desktop application using what looks just like HTML/CSS/JS. They didn't.

The source code you link to is Nitro for web, it's a Chrome extension.

The source for the desktop version is different and is hosted over at launchpad:

- [Nitrotasks Desktop](https://launchpad.net/nitrotasks/) project page
- [Nitrotasks Desktop Source Code](https://launchpad.net/nitrotasks/trunk/1.2.5/+download/nitrotasks_1.2.5.tar.gz) download link

The desktop version is a Python application, as you can see from [browsing around the code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~cooperjona/nitrotasks/quickly_trunk/files/head:/nitrotasks/).

It has files like `NitroTasksWindow.py`, and uses GTK for windowing.